# Filter uppercase with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I didn't find how to uppercase or uppercase first letter in `ng-options`.

My select:

```
<select ng-model="company.currency.code" ng-options="currency.code as currency.code for currency in currency_list>
</select>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.currency_list = [
    {
        code: 'eur'
    }, {
        code: 'usd'
    }
];
```

I'd like to print "EUR", "USD", or "Eur", "Usd" without looping manually my object.

Is that possible to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
ng-options="currency.code as (currency.code | uppercase) for currency in currency_list"
```

See the filter docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase

Answer (score 4):

Use **[uppercase](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase)** filter.

Take a look at this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currency_list = [
    {
        code: 'eur'
    }, {
        code: 'usd'
    }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <select ng-model="company.currency.code" ng-options="currency.code as (currency.code | uppercase) for currency in currency_list | uppercase">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Like those inline-runnable code a lot! It took me some googling to find the recent blog entry about runnable code (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ ).  Neat. Will do that too, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a css approach for this by attaching a class to the

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currency_list = [
      {
          code: 'eur'
      }, {
          code: 'usd'
      }
    ];
});
```

```css
.text-capitalize{ text-transform: capitalize }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <select 
      class="text-capitalize"
      ng-model="company.currency.code"
      ng-options="currency.code as currency.code for currency in currency_list">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this attribute:
`ng-options="currency.code | uppercase for currency in currency_list"`